# Strange intermittent error handling bug when calling UserPrinciapl.GetGroups in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, active-directory

## Background

We have an asp.net 4.0 web application written in C# that calls a .net 3.5 web service written in C#.  The web service is passed a user id and returns a list of data depending on the active directory groups the user belongs to.

The web service uses .net 3.5 version of System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement to get the Sids of the groups the user belongs to.

The call to UserPrincipal.GetGroups fails intermittently with the error below.  There were very long periods of time between occurrences but when it did occur it occurred repeatedly for several minutes.  The issue occurred for different AD users.

The stack trace of this exception made no sense to us.  We spent a lot of time looking at the Microsoft AD code in Reflector/ILSpy but couldn't get beyond the call to IADsPathName.Retrieve.

## Exception

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.get_Position()
at System.Drawing.UnsafeNativeMethods.ComStreamFromDataStream.Seek(Int64 offset, Int32 origin)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UnsafeNativeMethods.IADsPathname.Retrieve(Int32 lnFormatType)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.LoadDomainInfo()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.get_DnsForestName()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOf(Principal p)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetGroupsHelper()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetGroups()
at Data.SoftwarePublishingItemData.GetSids(String requestedForUserId)
at Data.SoftwarePublishingItemData.GetSoftwarePublishingItems(IDatabaseContext dbContext, GetSoftwarePublishingItemsSettings settings, XBXmlDocument parameters)
at Web.GetSoftwarePublishingItems.GetFlexiFieldData(String xml)
```

## Code to reproduce

***Please note, the CauseNotSupportedException method is mimicking code that is not running in our application but in code somewhere else in the environment that we are not on control of.***

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CauseNotSupportedException();

        string samAccountName = "domain.user";

        using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAccountName))
            {
                if (userPrincipal == null)
                    throw new ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException();

                using (var groups = userPrincipal.GetGroups())
                {
                    foreach (GroupPrincipal group in groups)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(group.Sid);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void CauseNotSupportedException()
    {
        using (var b = new Bitmap(500, 500, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            b.Save(new FakeStream(), ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

**Implementation of Stream to mimic HttpResponseStream behaviour**

```
public class FakeStream : Stream
{
    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }
    public override bool CanSeek { get { return false; } }
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }

    public override void Flush() { }

    public override long Length { get { throw new NotSupportedException("No Seek"); } }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { throw new NotSupportedException("No Seek"); }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException("No Seek"); }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Write only stream");
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("net_noseek");
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value) { }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { }
}
```

## Questions

1. If you run the example above the error that occurs in the CauseNotSupportedException method is thrown in the call to GetGroups.  How can that be?  Any theories or further insight would be appreciated.
2. Any suggestions as to how to investigate further?
3. Any better suggestions than catching the exception and retrying?  That is our current work around.

Thanks.

***Clarification***

I'm not sure how clear I've been in my explanation so here's some clarification.  Firstly, I am happy with the active directory code that gets the Sids.  That does what I want it to do and I don't think the problem is with that as such.  The real issue is that when an error occurs in other unrelated code (it's not in our app) the error manifests in the GetGroups call, hence the strange stack trace with the error originally occurring at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.get_Position().  In the sample app NotSupportedException occurs in CauseNotSupportedException but the code does not break there, it breaks on the call to GetGroups.  If you comment out CauseNotSupportedException() in the sample app the error never occurs.

It is unclear to me how this can possibly happen.

Comment: Question, are you trying to find if users are in a particular group or not.. I am trying to gain a better understanding of what you are truly looking for.. I may have a suggestion on a better approach in regards to coding.. here is a link that will help as well I will paste 2 code snippets below that should help you get at what you need easier. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.  What I need is a list of Sids of the groups a user is a member of.  I am currently using the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace (UserPrincipal.GetGroups is in that namespace).  So my code sample is very similar to the one you posted below.  The code I have gets what I want fine, it's just the intermittent error occurring caused by unrelated code that I am trying to understand.  If you have time it would be worth running the sample code and stepping through it.

Comment: ok not a problem.. it was hard to determine at first what you were wanting.. my apologies you would still need to check that property or the (string)Properties["samAccountName"][0].ToString() because this would be an Object at this time.. hope this makes sense..

Comment: Sorry, I find it hard to write these things giving enough info but still being clear.  The weird bit is that when the error occurs in CauseNotSupportedException it then jumps to GetGroups and throws the exception there.

Comment: I can't tell without seeing all your code there are many ways to get what you are looking for but I am trying to get you answers that will help you in regards to your code incase you need to fix or refactor something

Comment: Thank you.  The code sample is complete in that it gets the Sids for all top level groups the user is a member of.  If you put it in a console app and run it it will demonstrate that problem I'm experiencing.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: basically if you are getting errors when there is a null value you will need to wrap that code check around an if else to handle it the current code is working..

Comment: Thanks.  There's not a null value.

Comment: so are you saying that you are still getting an error..? please confirm if you are having the same issue..

Comment: I am able to get the Sids fine.  The error occurs intermittently in production code.  The sample console app is a way of reliably reproducing what is happening in production.  Please try running this and I think it will become clear exactly what the strange error behaviour is.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have AD on this machine that is why I was wondering where exactly it's erroring out..

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for your perseverance.  I have added a clarification which I hope will help.  This is the strangest issue I have ever come across and I don't think it is a problem with the AD code itself.  It seems to be some strange behaviour in the CLR.

Comment: This is going to sound like a rather odd question but do you have Directory Browsing turned on .. the webserver end..?

Comment: also now that I am thinking about it.. if you are doing this via HTTP can you paste how your configuration settings appear in your web.config file for <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">

Comment: Thanks but the console app proves that it is nothing to do with Http in our application and nothing to do with the web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After raising a support call Microsoft have issued a hot fix for this issue.  See link below.

The stated cause is:
"This issue occurs because the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace is a thin wrapper for the native API Active Directory Service Interfaces (ADSI). The IErrorInfo interface that is implemented by the IADsPathName interface responds to exceptions that ADSI does not throw. When there is no ADSI exception on the stack, the IErrorInfo interface throws the exception that is at the top of the stack, even if the exception is handled by another handler in the application."

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2683913

Thank you to those who offered suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 or up, you can use the new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace which makes this a lot easier than it used to be.

Read all about it here: [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5][1]

Basically, you need to have a "principal context" (typically your domain), a user principal, and then you get its groups very easily:

```
public List<GroupPrincipal> GetGroups(string userName)
{
   List<GroupPrincipal> result = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

   // establish domain context
   PrincipalContext yourDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

   // find your user
   UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, username);

   // if found - grab its groups
   if(user != null)
   {
      PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

      // iterate over all groups
      foreach(Principal p in groups)
      {
         // make sure to add only group principals or change this to add to a list or varible if needed.
         if(p is GroupPrincipal)
         {
             result.Add(p);
         }
      }
   }

   return result;
}
```

In order to access certain properties, which are not surfaced on the `UserPrincipal` object, you need to dig into the underlying `DirectoryEntry`:

```
public string GetDepartment(Principal principal)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    DirectoryEntry de = (principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);

    if (de != null)
    {
       if (de.Properties.Contains("samAccountName"))
       {
          result = de.Properties["samAccountName"][0].ToString();
       }
    }

    return result;
}

//Change this Method to fit what ever your needs desire.. 
public string GetDepartment(string username)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    // if you do repeated domain access, you might want to do this *once* outside this method, 
    // and pass it in as a second parameter!
    PrincipalContext yourDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

    // find the user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, username);

    // if user is found
    if(user != null)
    {
       // get DirectoryEntry underlying it
       DirectoryEntry de = (user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);

       if (de != null)
       {
          if (de.Properties.Contains("department"))
          {
             result = de.Properties["department"][0].ToString();
          }
       }
    }

    return result;
}
```